# Algolia hierarchical Menu issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algolia

I have been using Algolia for React and I am having issues with its hierarchical Menu. When I select the third level of category from the menu everything else disappears from the screen and only the category and its parent category remains there.

> Before clicking on the third level category

[image: Before clicking on the third level category]

> After clicking on the third level category. ( All other categories are gone )
> [image: After clicking on the third level category]

This is my code for getting the categories and showing them on screen.

```
const HierarchicalMenu = ({ items, refine, createURL }) => {
const classes = useStyles();
console.log(items);
return (
    <ul style={{ marginBottom: 0, paddingLeft: 20, marginLeft: 0 }}>
        {items.map((item) => {
            console.log(item.label);
            console.log(item?.items ?? []);
            return (
                <li className={classes.categoryTitle} key={item.label}>
                    <a
                        href={createURL(item.value)}
                        className={cx(classes.categoryItem, item.isRefined ? 'selected' : null)}
                        onClick={(event) => {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            refine(item.value);
                        }}
                    >
                        {item.isRefined && item.items && <ArrowDropUpIcon />}
                        {!item.isRefined && <ArrowDropDownIcon />}
                        {item.label} <span>({item.count})</span>
                    </a>
                    {item.items && (
                        <HierarchicalMenu items={item.items} refine={refine} createURL={createURL} />
                    )}
                </li>
            );
        })}
    </ul>
);
};

const CustomHierarchicalMenu = connectHierarchicalMenu(HierarchicalMenu);



const CategoryFilter = () => {

return (
<CustomHierarchicalMenu attributes={['categories.lvl0', 'categories.lvl1', 'categories.lvl2']} />
  )

  }
```

This is how I have created the categories node in Alglolia

[image: Algolia doc with categories values]